# Static text on rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I've been trying different ways to create the url like this:

> http://www.domain.com/postal-zip/123456

I've tried:

> RewriteRule ^postal-zip/([0-9]+)$ code.php?thecode=$1 [L]

and

> RewriteRule ^postal-zip/([0-9]+)$ postal-zip/code.php?thecode=$1 [L]

and a few more things but I have not got the result, does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your rules look okay. It sounds like `mod-rewrite` is not turned on.

First, before your rules, make sure you have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

Next, for this to work, mod_rewrite must **both** be installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();` By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf` and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: already had the running along with some htaccess rules working, but that last did not work, now it works, what I did was: move the rule to the top, right after the RewriteEngine On 
really Thanks for the reply :)